# Matlab ( Input as string -> function -> plot it ) GUI

Tags: matlab

I'm trying to get a function from edit text, then write it as function so I can plot it. However, What I did isn't working :(. Please if you can help me with this.

Can you fix the problem here. I'm trying to get the function from a user as string then write change it to a function, and the output is going to be the plot of the input function.By the way I'm using gui, which have (edit box, pushbutton, and axes).

```
t=0:0.1:10;
maxi= get(handles.edit1, 'String');
whatever= strcat('@(x) ', maxi);
fh = str2func(whatever);
plot(t,fh(t))
```

Please explain what's the mistake that I did thanks, or show me what's the wright way to do it.

Comment: Sorry I mean (Input-> string -> function -> plot)

Comment: Thanks It's really worked. Can you explain what Char did? Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`maxi= get(handles.edit1, 'String');` gets the string data from the `editbox` as a cell array. So, before using into `strcat`, you need to convert `maxi` from the cell array version to a char array with `char(..)`.

Thus, the only edit you need to make in your codes would be -

```
whatever= strcat('@(x) ', char(maxi));
```